# How to hide the app icon programatically in iphone app

Tags: ios, xcode, gps

I am making an app in which i will track user location.
so the point is that whenever user install the app, after installation the app will be hide and works in background and give data of user location through gps to server.
so i want how to hide app icon and works done in background.
please help.

Comment: Is this meant for the App Store? If so, you can't.

Comment: no..its only for my personal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove your App icon from the home screen completely, you can make it invisible. However, the icon, while invisible, can still be tapped.

Here is how you make your App invisible:

1. Create a completely transparent PNG file, and use it as Icon. Enable the "Prerendered" checkbox to make sure no gradient is applied to your icon.
2. In your .plist file, remove the string "${PRODUCT_NAME}" from "Bundle display name"

**Also, your App would never be approved for the App Store that way.**

Comment: Is there any other way? Please let me know.